# How to detect HDMI usage on Samsung Galaxy S II

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, galaxy, hdmi

Is it possible to detect (either Java or native code) if the HDMI output is used on Samsung Galaxy S II? I was looking at system properties and also `sysfs` but couldn't find any info related to HDMI output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

The HDMI API interface allows a developer to do these things:

```
Make status enquiries about the HDMI port
Set the HDMI resolution and reset it back to what it was
Render content to the HDMI port
Assert Digital Rights Management, using HDCP
```

link: http://developer.motorola.com/docs/motorola-hdmi-dual-screen-api/

Hope that helps! =]